# Assigning public IP address to a VM hosted on a server behind NAT

Tags: networking, nat, linux-kvm

I have a pool of public IP addresses (95.xxx.xxx.196 - 254). I also have a server hosting KVM machines. It has a private IP address 10.0.0.1 which is NATed by the router to the 95.xxx.xxx.200 address so that it's available to the Internet using this public IP.

VMs hosted on it are routed the same way - my MikroTik router binds 10.0.0.xxx addresses to 95.xxx.xxx.xxx and it works (meaning I can access my VMs from the Internet). Now I want to assign one of the VMs a public IP directly. It needs to work somewhat like for example a VPS hosted at OVH - you log into the server by SSH and running `ip -a` shows only one interface with a public IP - how to achieve the same with KVM?

I tried to assign an external IP address to the VM with gateway set to the host internal IP but it didn't work. Nobody could ping it, including the host.

How to set up KVM, the host server, and the router to assign a public IP to the virtual machine (like on a VPS)?

Comment: Can you use custom MAC addresses on the network?

Comment: Yes, I can. Can you explain how could it help me?

Comment: Wouldn't bridging the VM to a host NIC that is attached to the router be enough? (Of course you have to configure the router to not do NAT for that public address)

Comment: I suppose you can also do ARP proxy (with e.g. a local route on the host) and do IP forwarding instead of switching/bridging.

Comment: What is the logic of trying this since you NAT local IPs to public ones and it works?

Comment: @TomYan , Host need to have an private IP only. I want it to stay behind NAT.

Comment: That isn't mutually exclusive with bridging / ARP proxying for the VM.

Comment: In fact, you can even add an indirect route in the router with the host as gateway for the VM's public IP. The main point is really just stop the router from doing NAT for that public IP. The remaining part is pretty much a matter of choice.